# Quadratic congruence $x^2+5x \equiv 12 \pmod{31} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, quadratic-residues

Does 
$$x^2+5x \equiv 12 \pmod{31} $$
have a solution?

Comment: Complete the square and use quadratic reciprocity, recalling that $16\equiv 2^{-1}\mod 31$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to:
$$ 4x^2 + 20x\equiv 48 \equiv 17\pmod{31}$$
or to:
$$ (2x+5)^2 \equiv  11\pmod{31} $$
hence it has two solutions iff $11$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{31}$. So, let us compute the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{11}{31}\right)$ through quadratic reciprocity:
$$\left(\frac{11}{31}\right) = - \left(\frac{31}{11}\right) = -\left(\frac{9}{11}\right) = -1.$$
No way, $11$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{31}$, hence there are no solutions.

Comment: Or, $11 \equiv -20 \equiv -144$. If $11$ were a square mod $31$, then so would $-1$, but this is false, because $31 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: @lhf: that is a nice (and elementary) alternative.